# MySQL Select Optimization: Explaion Select rows result

Tags: mysql, select, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, explain

I have two tables called parent and children. Looking like this:

```
  parent{id, name}
  children{id, name, parent_id}
```

I have setup a foreign key constraint on children table. and execute this query:

```
  EXPLAIN Select child.name AS childname, par.name AS parentname
  FROM children AS child
  INNER JOIN parent AS par ON child.parent_id = par.id
```

The result shows for parent table having `key`, `ref` column as NULL and `rows` having 16007. This would explain why the simple query would take very very long to execute. If I comment out `par.name` on the select clause the query returns data quickly. Isn't the correct result would be the `key` and `ref` should have values right? How can I make it so?

Here is the actual table with EXPLAIN

[image]

It is quite wierd because I have setup the necessary index already and the EXPLAIN SELECT cannot locate the `key` for the foreign key.

Here below is the actual CREATE TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE `am_asset_trx_voice` (
  `am_asset_trx_voice_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `am_asset_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` VARCHAR(255),
  `date_updated` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`am_asset_trx_voice_id`,`am_asset_id`),
  KEY `fk_owned_by_id_voice` (`owned_by_id`),
  KEY `fk_bonded_id_voice` (`bonded_id`),
  KEY `fk_am_asset_id_voice` (`am_asset_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_am_asset_id_voice` FOREIGN KEY (`am_asset_id`) REFERENCES `am_asset` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bonded_id_voice` FOREIGN KEY (`bonded_id`) REFERENCES `am_bonded_typedef` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_owned_by_id_voice` FOREIGN KEY (`owned_by_id`) REFERENCES `am_owned_by_typedef` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=14766 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `am_owned_by_typedef` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `am_bonded_typedef` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Is there somewhere I have not looked over? some angle I have not looked into? Please help.

Comment: please share the `create table code` of both `parent` and `children` table.

Comment: updated the post with screenshot of EXPLAIN SELECT

Comment: I asked for full `create table structure` of both tables.

Comment: Updated the post again.

Comment: When you go commenting out columns from a query you also need to re-run `EXPLAIN SELECT` with the revised query.  You have not shown us the "asset" table, which is clearly shown in the query plan, or the query itself -- which I suspect contains a logical error that introduces the join buffer.  The `type` on the second table seems like it should be `eq_ref`, not `ALL`, if the query is written correctly.